# How can I change the behavior of a static method at runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way to modify the behavior of a static method at runtime?

for example:

Say I have this class

```
public class Utility {

    public static void DoSomething(string data){
        //...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
typeof(Utility).SetMethod("DoSomething", (data) => { /*Do something else...*/ });
```

Such that if you call `Utility.DoSomething` it executes the new code?

Comment: You could store the lambda in a variable maybe and have `DoSomething` invoke the variable? Then you can change that variable whenever you want to store a new lambda. But I'm not a C# dev...

Comment: I've provided an answer, because it's pretty simple. But, I believe this question belongs on SO.

Comment: Also using a non-static method is probably a better idea.

Comment: Not to be a pain, but isn't this question kind of off-topic since it's pretty much a how-to coding request?

Comment: @Quezocotl: It's a "code is design" question.  The kinds of questions we want to close here (aggressively) are the "fix my broken code" questions.

Comment: Haha!  I was right and the Stack Overloard was wrong!  :) lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want to do is pass the behavior you want as another parameter into the function.

```
public static void DoSomething(string data, Action<string> operation)
{
    operation(data);
}
```

This is an oversimplified example, of course.  What you actually wind up doing in your own code is going to depend on what `operation` actually does.

---

If you're trying to modify the behavior of an existing, compiled, in-production method, and cannot overload or override the method in the usual ways, the only way I know of to do that is CIL Rewriting, possibly using an [Aspect Weaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_weaver).

Comment: But, if this is the solution, why not just call `operation` directly?

Comment: It's a contrived example.  For this particular scenario, that's exactly what I would do.  But the OP said he wanted to change out the behavior of the method.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I kinda made the assumption that he couldn't change the DoSomething method.  Otherwise, he wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: I would just create a new class that inherits from Utility.  I don't like the idea of injecting code into a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

```
public class Utility {

    public static Action<String> _DoSomething;

    public static void DoSomething(string data){
        if (_DoSomething != null) {
            _DoSomething();
            return;
        }

        // default behavior here.
    }
}
```

And to mask the default behavior:

```
Utility._DoSomething = (data) => { /* do something else */ };
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need a member variable to make this work, unless you're setting up some sort of "subscriber" scenario.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not 100% sure what you mean. But, the member variable + method combination is there to avoid breakages when `_DoSomething = null` is called. ... Well ... unless it's *supposed* to break in that case!

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why you wouldn't just create a new class that inherits from Utility and define a new function that does what you want.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            Utility.DoSomething("TEST");
        } else
        {
            Util1.DoSomething("TEST");
        }
    }
}

public class Utility
{
    public static void DoSomething(string data)
    {
        //Perform some action
    }
}

abstract class Util1 : Utility
{
    public static new void DoSomething(string data)
    {
        //Perform a different action
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, isn't this question off-topic since the OP is asking us to debug code?  Shouldn't this belong on SO?

Answer (score -1):

I think although it *is* possible to do this you should ask yourself: "Why do I *need* this functionality"? Usually a method stays as is, and does what it is supposed to do according to its interface which is **given by its name and signature**. So while you *can* add additional logic by adding an `Action<T>`-parameter to your signature you should ask yourself if this won´t break the contract of the interface and therefor **what the method was designed for**.

Having said this you should consider either *overwrite* your method if the functionality you need is some kind of "making the same things differently then the parent-class" or *extend* it by adding a dependency into your consuming class and add some methods to that class that extent the functionality provided by the contained class (see also [favour composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance))

```
class MyClass {
    Utility MyUtility;

    void ExtraMethod() { /* ... */ }
}
```

EDIT: As you´re using a static method the opportunity on overwriting is obsolete. However IMO that sounds like a great design-flaw.